# Hatten är din - original lyrics

Tags: lyrics

What are the **original** lyrics of "Hatten är din"?
I am not talking about the English or Swedish lyrics.

Comment: The original song THANKS to [Wikipedia article]( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatten_%C3%A4r_din?wprov=sfla1) is by Lebanese musician Azar Habib. " In 1984, Habib recorded "Meen ma Kenty/Habbeetek" (Whoever you are/I Loved You, or I Fell In Love With You) in Arabic for his ''Ajbeen el Layl'' album. The Swedish lyrics were part of the whole joke video which came along in 2000. But due to seeming omnipresence of the Swedish/English lyrics, original lyrics hard to find.

Comment: @Angst couldn't this be an answer?

Comment: @Bebs Actually it should be easy -- any Arabic speaker presumably can answer the question. But probably none such has read it yet.

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen, If you mean that you need someone to translate and transcribe the lyrics for you, I'm not sure this is the proper SE community.

Comment: Maybe you should ask about the lyrics in another forum, on SE or elsewhere.  But pls keep this question open as I want to know the answer now...although I never knew about this meme until now- and if you find an answer, putting it with the background that is in my comment, that would be a complete answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Miin%20Ma%20Kenti%20lyrics) gives the lyrics (via Musixmatch, see end of post), transliteration, and translation reproduced in full below. Listening to the [original recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eUHN4iq1Y4s) on YouTube, and following along with the transliteration, suggests that the transliterated lyrics are fairly accurate.

As a double-check, I also ran the Google/Musixmatch lyrics through SYSTRAN, getting [these results](https://translate.systran.net/translationTools/text?source=ar&target=en&input=%D9%88%D9%8A%D9%86%20%D9%85%D8%A7%20%D9%83%D9%86%D8%AA%D9%90%20%D8%AA%D9%83%D9%88%D9%86%D9%8A%0D%0A%D9%85%D9%8A%D9%86%20%D9%85%D8%A7%20%D9%83%D9%86%D8%AA%D9%90%20%D8%AA%D9%83%D9%88%D9%86%D9%8A%0D%0A%D8%AD%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%83...%20%D8%AD%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%83...%0D%0A%D8%AD%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%83...%20%D8%AD%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%83...%0D%0A%D8%A8%D8%B9%D9%82%D9%84%D9%8A%20%D9%88%D8%AC%D9%86%D9%88%D9%86%D9%8A%0D%0A%D8%A8%D8%B9%D9%82%D9%84%D9%8A%20%D9%88%D8%AC%D9%86%D9%88%D9%86%D9%8A%0D%0A%D8%AD%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%83...%20%D8%AD%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%83...%0D%0A%D8%AD%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%83...%20%D8%AD%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%83...%0D%0A%D8%A8%D8%AD%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%8A%20%D8%A8%D8%AE%D9%8A%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%8A...%0D%0A%D8%A8%D9%81%D9%83%D8%B1%D9%8A%20%D8%A8%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%8A...%0D%0A%D8%A8%D9%82%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%8A%20%D9%88%D8%B9%D9%8A%D9%88%D9%86%D9%8A...%0D%0A%D8%AD%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%83...%20%D8%AD%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%83...%0D%0A%D8%A3%D9%88%D9%84%20%D9%83%D9%84%D9%85%D8%A9%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%8A%20%D8%AD%D9%83%D9%8A%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%87%D8%A7%0D%0A%D8%A8%D8%B9%D8%AF%D8%A7%20%D8%A8%D9%81%D9%83%D8%B1%D9%8A%2C%20%D9%85%D8%A7%20%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%87%D8%A7...%0D%0A%D8%A3%D9%88%D9%84%20%D9%83%D9%84%D9%85%D8%A9%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%8A%20%D8%AD%D9%83%D9%8A%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%87%D8%A7%0D%0A%D8%A8%D8%B9%D8%AF%D8%A7%20%D8%A8%D9%81%D9%83%D8%B1%D9%8A%2C%20%D9%85%D8%A7%20%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%87%D8%A7...%0D%0A%D9%82%D9%84%D8%AA%D9%8A%20%D8%AD%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%83%20%D9%88%D9%84%D9%88%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%87%D8%A7%0D%0A%D9%82%D9%84%D8%AA%D9%8A%20%D8%AD%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%83%20%D9%88%D9%84%D9%88%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%87%D8%A7...%0D%0A%D9%85%D8%A7%20%D8%AC%D9%86%20%D8%AC%D9%86%D9%88%D9%86%D9%8A%20%D9%88%20%D8%AD%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%83...%0D%0A%D9%85%D8%A7%20%D8%AC%D9%86%20%D8%AC%D9%86%D9%88%D9%86%D9%8A%20%D9%88%20%D8%AD%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%83...%0D%0A%D9%85%D8%A7%20%D8%AC%D9%86%20%D8%AC%D9%86%D9%88%D9%86%D9%8A%20%D9%88%20%D8%AD%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%83...%0D%0A%D9%85%D8%A7%20%D8%AC%D9%86%20%D8%AC%D9%86%D9%88%D9%86%D9%8A%20%D9%88%20%D8%AD%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%83...%0D%0A%D8%AD%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%83...%20%D8%AD%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%83...%0D%0A%D8%AD%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%83...%20%D8%AD%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%83...%0D%0A%D9%84%D9%88%20%D9%85%D8%A7%20%D9%82%D9%84%D8%AA%D9%8A%20%D8%AD%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%8A%D9%86%D9%8A%0D%0A%D9%85%D8%A7%20%D8%A7%D8%AA%D9%87%D9%86%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%8A%20%D9%88%20%D9%87%D9%86%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%8A%D9%86%D9%8A%0D%0A%D9%84%D9%88%20%D9%85%D8%A7%20%D9%82%D9%84%D8%AA%D9%8A%20%D8%AD%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%8A%D9%86%D9%8A%0D%0A%D9%85%D8%A7%20%D8%A7%D8%AA%D9%87%D9%86%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%8A%20%D9%88%20%D9%87%D9%86%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%8A%D9%86%D9%8A%0D%0A%D8%B9%20%D8%AF%D9%86%D9%8A%D9%8A%20%D8%AC%D8%AF%D9%8A%D8%AF%D8%A9%20%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%82%D9%8A%D9%86%D9%8A%0D%0A%D8%B9%20%D8%AF%D9%86%D9%8A%D9%8A%20%D8%AC%D8%AF%D9%8A%D8%AF%D8%A9%20%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%82%D9%8A%D9%86%D9%8A%0D%0A%D9%82%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%83%20%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%8A%20%D9%88%20%D9%82%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%8A%20%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%83%0D%0A%D9%82%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%83%20%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%8A%20%D9%88%20%D9%82%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%8A%20%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%83%0D%0A%D9%82%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%83%20%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%8A%20%D9%88%20%D9%82%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%8A%20%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%83%0D%0A%D9%82%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%83%20%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%8A%20%D9%88%20%D9%82%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%8A%20%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%83%0D%0A%D8%AD%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%83%20%D8%AD%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%83...%0D%0A%D8%AD%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%83%20%D8%AD%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%83...%0D%0A%D9%88%D9%8A%D9%86%20%D9%85%D8%A7%20%D9%83%D9%86%D8%AA%D9%90%20%D8%AA%D9%83%D9%88%D9%86%D9%8A%0D%0A%D9%85%D9%8A%D9%86%20%D9%85%D8%A7%20%D9%83%D9%86%D8%AA%D9%90%20%D8%AA%D9%83%D9%88%D9%86%D9%8A%20%D8%AA%D9%83%D9%88%D9%86%D9%8A%0D%0A%D8%AD%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%83...%20%D8%AD%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%83...%0D%0A%D8%AD%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%83...%20%D8%AD%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%83...%0D%0A%D8%A8%D8%B9%D9%82%D9%84%D9%8A%20%D9%88%D8%AC%D9%86%D9%88%D9%86%D9%8A%0D%0A%D8%A8%D8%B9%D9%82%D9%84%D9%8A%20%D9%88%D8%AC%D9%86%D9%88%D9%86%D9%8A%0D%0A%D8%AD%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%83...%20%D8%AD%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%83...%0D%0A%D8%AD%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%83...%20%D8%AD%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%83...%0D%0A%D8%A8%D8%AD%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%8A%20%D8%A8%D8%AE%D9%8A%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%8A...%0D%0A%D8%A8%D9%81%D9%83%D8%B1%D9%8A%20%D8%A8%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%8A...%0D%0A%D8%A8%D9%82%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%8A%20%D9%88%D8%B9%D9%8A%D9%88%D9%86%D9%8A...%0D%0A%D8%AD%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%83...%20%D8%AD%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%83...), which are substantially the same, but with some differences in nuance.

**EDIT:** For information on the relationship between the Arabic original and the Swedish meme lyrics, along with English translation of the Swedish, see [here](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/10987/how-do-the-hatten-%C3%A4r-din-meme-lyrics-correspond-to-the-original-miin-ma-kenti)

Where have you been?
وين ما كنتِ تكوني
wayn ma knt takuni

Who were you not?
مين ما كنتِ تكوني
mayn ma knt takuni

I loved you ... I loved you ...
حبيتك... حبيتك...
habytik... habitik...

I loved you ... I loved you ...
حبيتك... حبيتك...
habytik... habitik...

In my mind and crazy
بعقلي وجنوني
bieaqli wajnuni

In my mind and crazy
بعقلي وجنوني
bieaqli wajnuni

I loved you ... I loved you ...
حبيتك... حبيتك...
habytik... habitik...

I loved you ... I loved you ...
حبيتك... حبيتك...
habytik... habitik...

In my imagination ...
بحالي بخيالي...
bihali bikhiali...

In my mind ...
بفكري ببالي...
bifakri bibali...

In my heart and eyes ...
بقلبي وعيوني...
biqalbi waeyuni...

I loved you ... I loved you ...
حبيتك... حبيتك...
habytik... habitik...

The first word we spoke
أول كلمة الي حكيناها
'awal kalimat 'iilay hakaynaha

Far from my mind, I won't forget it ...
بعدا بفكري, ما بانساها...
buedana bifkari, ma biansaha...

The first word we spoke
أول كلمة الي حكيناها
'awal kalimat 'iilay hakaynaha

Far from my mind, I won't forget it ...
بعدا بفكري, ما بانساها...
buedana bifkari, ma biansaha...

You said I loved you and had it not
قلتي حبيتك ولولاها
qulati hibiyatak walawlaha

You said I loved you and if it weren't for her ...
قلتي حبيتك ولولاها...
qulati hibiytuk waluulaha...

I'm not crazy and I loved you ...
ما جن جنوني و حبيتك...
ma jan jinawni w hibiatik...

I'm not crazy and I loved you ...
ما جن جنوني و حبيتك...
ma jan jinawni w hibiatik...

I'm not crazy and I loved you ...
ما جن جنوني و حبيتك...
ma jan jinawni w hibiatik...

I'm not crazy and I loved you ...
ما جن جنوني و حبيتك...
ma jan jinawni w hibiatik...

I loved you ... I loved you ...
حبيتك... حبيتك...
habytik... habitik...

I loved you ... I loved you ...
حبيتك... حبيتك...
habytik... habitik...

If you did not love me
لو ما قلتي حبيتيني
law ma qulti hbytyni

What did you mean and did you?
ما اتهنيتي و هنيتيني
ma atahaniti w hanitayni

If you did not love me
لو ما قلتي حبيتيني
law ma qulti hbytyni

What did you mean and did you?
ما اتهنيتي و هنيتيني
ma atahaniti w hanitayni

A new world for my eyes
ع دنيي جديدة لاقيني
e duniyiy jadidat laqini

A new world for my eyes
ع دنيي جديدة لاقيني
e duniyiy jadidat laqini

Your heart is my home and my heart is your home
قلبك بيتي و قلبي بيتك
qalbik bayti w qalbi baytik

Your heart is my home and my heart is your home
قلبك بيتي و قلبي بيتك
qalbik bayti w qalbi baytik

Your heart is my home and my heart is your home
قلبك بيتي و قلبي بيتك
qalbik bayti w qalbi baytik

Your heart is my home and my heart is your home
قلبك بيتي و قلبي بيتك
qalbik bayti w qalbi baytik

I loved you ...
حبيتك حبيتك...
habiytk habyatik...

I loved you ...
حبيتك حبيتك...
habiytk habyatik...

Where have you been?
وين ما كنتِ تكوني
wayn ma knt takuni

Who weren't you being?
مين ما كنتِ تكوني تكوني
mayn ma knt takuni takuni

I loved you ... I loved you ...
حبيتك... حبيتك...
habytik... habitik...

I loved you ... I loved you ...
حبيتك... حبيتك...
habytik... habitik...

In my mind and crazy
بعقلي وجنوني
bieaqli wajnuni

In my mind and crazy
بعقلي وجنوني
bieaqli wajnuni

I loved you ... I loved you ...
حبيتك... حبيتك...
habytik... habitik...

I loved you ... I loved you ...
حبيتك... حبيتك...
habytik... habitik...

In my imagination ...
بحالي بخيالي...
bihali bikhiali...

In my mind ...
بفكري ببالي...
bifakri bibali...

With my heart and eyes ...
بقلبي وعيوني...
biqalbi waeyuni...

I loved you ... I loved you ...
حبيتك... حبيتك...
habytik... habitik...

[Google's] Source: [Musixmatch](https://www.musixmatch.com/lyrics/Azar-Habib-2/Miin-Ma-Kenti) (NOTE: Musixmatch indicates the lyrics are "waiting for review")

Comment: Finally! Now what could make this go viral would be if we also figured out how to match it up with the Swedish lyrics. For instance, is "bihali bikhiali..." matched with "vi har det för jävligt"?

Comment: "wayn ma knt takuni" = "vinna kinkig rolig"

Comment: It looks like "Where have you been?" == "Who were you not?" which is odd

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen [Enjoy!](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/10987/how-do-the-hatten-%c3%a4r-din-meme-lyrics-correspond-to-the-original-miin-ma-kenti/10988#10988)